# Best distance algorithm

Tags: python

So, I currently have a problem to solve a best decision algorithm in Python. I have a road to browse and a number of hostels. Each day I pay a penalty of `(200 - p)²` with `p` the distance browse. I want to search the path with the less penalty. To solve that, I made this algorithm:

```
def hotels(d):
    p  = 200 + d[0]
    
    if len(d) == 1:
        return 0
   
    bestdist = (10000, 0)

    for i in range(1, len(d)):
        if  (p - d[i])**2 < bestdist[0]:
            bestdist = ((p - d[i])**2, i)
    
    for j in range (bestdist[1]):
        d.pop(0)

    return hotels(d) + (200 - bestdist[0])**2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = [0, 150, 200, 500, 900]
    print(hotels(d))
```

The problem is: `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`
I don't know how to solve that so if you have any advice or correction I'll take it.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Stepping into your code will show that after the first recursive call your list never changes so you have an infinite recursion loop... I suggest you use a debugger and find out what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to prevent stack overflows. You can see that with;

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

To change the default recursion limit;

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

But doing so might be dangerous for certain situations.

Comment: I doubt that will help, taking in count there is an infinite recursion loop...

Comment: Did you actually try that solution on the given code?

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm you made will perform recursion `len(d)` times. One solution is to change the recursion limit using `sys` to a value higher than that like so:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10*len(d))
```

However, if that doesn't work either, I suggest changing your algorithms into a `while len(d)>1:` function so that it does not run into recursion error at all.

Comment: I doubt that will help, taking in count there is an infinite recursion loop...